# Where to upload files from cordova app to reach the files with no cost?

Tags: javascript, php, cordova, hosting, image-uploading

I am trying to build a cordova app that everyone can upload files to a certain place so that I can reach it later.

I have tried using a free hosted website and made an upload.php, but free hosters don't let uploading via scripts.

I have tried uploading to a shared drive folder but it is really complicated and users need to sign in to their drive account to use this property.

I have tried sending email with php but free servers don't let this too.

How can I store the files uploaded from different devices via a cordova app with no cost?

In my cordova app I use file transfer plugin:

```js
ft.upload(....);
```

I want to remind that what I am looking for is not a localhost because I want to upload files when I am not connected to the local network too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on the file sizes you plan to upload.

There are several well-known hosters where you can get storage for cheap / for free.

You could try:

- [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/pricing) - it has a free tier that gives you `5 GB` in their [Cloud Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage).
- [Amazon AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/de/s3/) - also `5 GB` free storage in S3, however only for 12 months.
- [Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing-summary/) - Google gives you a `5 GB` free tier as well, and additionally 300$ of credit on signup.

There are probably many more such services, this is just a small list of the most well-known ones :)

Comment: **Beware of Firebase**, because Google likes to provide services for free for several years, then suddenly start charging for their use with a 30-day notice (e.g. Maps API) Those "5 GB free" can become "50 MB free" next month.

Comment: @andreszs oh, that's good to know - what a bummer that they pull such a sneaky move on their free limits.